# MVC3 and Active Directory Federation Services

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, active-directory, wif, adfs

I have a MVC3 application that uses Windows authentication and works great if we deploy it on a server that is in the same domain with the users that access it.

I have a request to deploy the application on a external server, like Amazon, and use ADFS to authenticate users with their domain credentials.

Does anyone have some tutorials how to implement this functionality into a MVC3 application? I didn't find any resources to help me with this issue.

Answer (score 2):

The core technology you need to look at is WIF (Windows Identity Foundation). The WIF SDK has plenty of examples of use, and I would start there.

This exact scenario is described in detail in this chapter:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff359102.aspx

I would suggest you should start with the intro sections of the same guide to understand how "claims based identity" works and the components involved.

For ADFS, I would suggest Lab 1 of this:

http://claimsid.codeplex.com/releases/view/68061